# Regular expression in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am a PHP coder and Javascript is new to me. Now I am reading some manuals about Regexp in Javascript. I can't do it work with jQuery.

Here are 2 examples.

http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/utG6H/ This one is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     str = "For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1";
     re = /(chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i;
     found = str.match(re);
    document.write(found);
 });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/QyFPE/1/ This one not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     str = "For more information, see Chapter 3.4.5.1";
     re = /(chapter \d+(\.\d)*)/i;
     found = str.match(re);
     $('div#write3').text(found);
 });
 </script>
```

The markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 
    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RegEx</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="write3"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a box for JavaScript code so you don't have to place a script tag in the HTML code box...

Comment: Jquery in only a javascript framework, for regexp you have to use javascript only. Javascript regexp are a little different from php regexp (but are similiar). Search on google...

Comment: This is not your problem but: you didn't declare your variables as locals, therefore they will be global (and global variables are baaaad).  You should write `var str = ...` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found is an array of matches (or null if nothing is found). Try changing this: `$('div#write3').text(found);`
to this `$('div#write3').text(found[0]);`

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) for more information.

Comment: Also, regular expressions are not jQuery specific, they're built into JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

[Drackir is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557124/regular-expression-in-jquery/4557153#4557153), but misses the more interesting point in the difference between your working and not working examples. `document.write` expects a string, and the `toString` method of the array is called automatically. jQuery's `text` can take a string or a function, so the array's `toString` is not automatically called.

The truly parallel examples are:

```
document.write(found);
```

and

```
$('div#write3').text(found.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually couldn't get the first example to show up, so I just focused on getting the second one to work.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/QyFPE/5/

1. You don't need to place the header, doctype, etc. in a jsfiddle, the blocks put the code in the appropriate place.
2. This should work, the only change I made was placing the content in the correct location(s) (and un-grouped your pattern for catching sub-group numerics in your chapter number)

Comment: Why $('div#write3').text('test'+found); works but $('div#write3').text(found); this doesn't?

Comment: @boyayeris - because JS loose typing means that a `string` plus an `array` causes `toString` to be called on the `array` and then the result is appended to the original `string`.

Comment: Because found is not a string, it's an array. Placing it as a concatenation forces javascript to cast it to a string (effectively dumping the objects out, comma-delimited). `''+found` should also work, or (as @Drackir pointed out) using it's Nth element will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The dom function document.write will accept an array name as parameter and can print all the elements

```
eg: <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var myarray = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myarray[i] = i;
}
document.write(myarray);
//  -->
</script>

will give 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Where as .text() function can only accept a string as parameter 
text( textString )
```